# How to get the selected Table View Cell on a different View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So I have a HistoryViewController, and when I tap on on a cell, I would like to get that value of that EXACT tapped cell on my DetailsViewController. That way when the user taps on the "Paid" button in my DetailsViewController, my HistoryViewController could mark that SPECIFIC cell "Paid".

EDIT:

Ok, so in my core data data model I have 2 entities. One is PeopleYouOwe. The other is PeopleWhoOweYou. Each entity has an attribute called "Paid". Paid is set to type BOOLEAN. When I tap a cell in my **HistoryTableViewController** it directs me to my **DetailViewController**. In my DetailViewController, I have a button called, "Paid." When the user taps this button, I want to know how I can make the cell that was tapped set to YES. After that, I would like to update my all my entities in CoreData so that the selected cell's attribute is SAVED to YES for the BOOLEAN value "Paid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a callback block property to your `DetailViewController`

```
@property (copy, readwrite, nonatomic) void (^payButtonActionHandler)(BOOL didPay)
```

The `didPay` parameter is useful if you want to create some kind of toggle.


And in your `DetailViewController` implementation:

```
- (void)paidButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (self.payButtonActionHandler)
        self.payButtonActionHandler(YES);
}
```

In your `HistoryViewController`:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 

        Person *person = // get your person object for this row
        DetailsViewController *vc = [DetailsViewController new];
        vc.payButtonActionHandler = ^(BOOL didPay) {

            // Update your entity
            person.hasPaid = didPay;

            // Reload the row
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
```

EDIT: You can check this website to remember the block syntax http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/

Comment: My history view controller is the TableViewController. My DetailsViewController is the regular view

Comment: so I could set id object = [YouOweArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] correct?

Comment: Exactly, and in the `selectionHandler` callback you could modify the actual object to a new status "PAID". Don't forget to reload the cell afterwards.

Comment: Don't you mean when I'm creating my Details Controller?

Comment: It's getting really confusing. Can you rephrase your initial question a little bit please?

Comment: I have rephrased it, and hopefully it can clear up some things ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47063/discussion-between-pacman321-and-doc92606)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a property of the same type as "value" in your DetailsViewController. When the user taps on a cell, on your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you pass that value to your DetailsViewController instance.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    MyObject *object = //.... get the value for that row
    myDetailsViewController.myselectedObject = object;
    // myDetailsViewController is the instance of the detailsViewController
    // ...
}
```

So, in your code in DetailsViewController you can manipulate that object using

```
[self myselectedObject]
```

for example for the paid button, you can set

```
self.myselectedObject.paid = YES;   //... or whatever you want to do
```